# Zend Auth - Indentities

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I have an auth resource in my library that is correctly returning one of the various statuses based on whether or not the user exists, wrong password, or correct password.  I'm trying to get the identity into my controllers though.  So in the auth resource I return the status along with user.  What needs to happen in my controllers then?  I've already handled logging in and redirecting to a different controller.  I'm trying to do something like $this->auth->authenticate() and $this->auth->getIdentity() to make sure that they are already authenticated and that they have an identity.  What do I need to do so that the identity gets passed around to all of the controllers that I call auth in predispatch?

Also, is there something in Zend Auth that keeps track of how many attempts at logging in have been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use stored the indentiy with Zend_Auth you can get it everywhere you want with:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()
```

see also [Matthews Tutorial](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/165-Login-and-Authentication-with-Zend-Framework.html) on Zend_Auth

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Is there anything inside zend framework that keeps track of the number of logon attempts?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the Zend_Auth singleton will work, but if you want to get the exact values returned by your resource, put something like this in your controller:

```
$auth = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->auth;
```